# Select and Replace Column Values With Data From Another Table

Tags: mysql

I have tables set up like so:

```
Fruits:
ID | Name
---+-----
 1 | Apple
 2 | Orange
 3 | Banana
 4 | Lemon
```

and

```
Groups
ID | Name | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3
---+------+--------+--------+-------
 1 |   A  |    1   |    2   |    3
 2 |   B  |    1   |    3   |  NULL
 3 |   C  |    4   |  NULL  |  NULL
```

What I'd like is to select from Groups and get the fruit name rather than its id like so:

```
ID | Name | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3
---+------+--------+--------+-------
 1 |   A  | Apple  | Orange | Banana
 2 |   B  | Apple  | Banana |  NULL
 3 |   C  | Lemon  |  NULL  |  NULL
```

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    G.ID,
    G.Name ,
    (SELECT Name FROM Fruits WHERE ID=G.Fruit1) AS Fruit1, 
    (SELECT Name FROM Fruits WHERE ID=G.Fruit2) AS Fruit2 ,
    (SELECT Name FROM Fruits WHERE ID=G.Fruit3) AS Fruit3  
FROM 
    Groups G
```

Comment: Well that seemed too easy.  Thanks.

Comment: How to do the same using JOIN statement?

Comment: If you want to use join query then you have to use 3 joining that would be time consuming.